# Hibernate does not save in DB using DAO object generated by visual-paradigm

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, visual-paradigm

I've a problem with hibernate. I'm trying to save an object into a relational db with hibernate using orm.jar library generated by visual-paradigm tool. The problem is that it does not work but the program does not give me exceptions.

I tried to change my code but the program catches an exception and does not work.

MAIN:

```
CoordinatorIntrusione c = CoordinatorIntrusione.getInstance();
    c.avviaRilevamento();

    c.notifyProximityBySerraID(1, 4);

    ArrayList<Integer> prova = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    prova.add(2);
    prova.add(1);
    prova.add(9);

    c.notifyImageBySerraID(1, prova);

    System.out.println("ecco");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    c.ripristinaRilevamento(1, "1");
```

COORDINATORINTRUSIONE:

```
    public class CoordinatorIntrusione {

        private volatile static CoordinatorIntrusione coordinator = null;
        private ThreadGroup groupBLThread;

        public int avviaRilevamento() {
            int code = 0;

            EntitySmartFarm esm = EntitySmartFarm.getInstance();
            EntityColtivazione[] colt = esm.getColtivazioniAttive();

            if(colt.length==0) {
                code=-1;
                return code;
            }

            for(int i=0; i<colt.length; i++) {

                EntitySerra serra = colt[i].getEntitySerra();
                int id = serra.getId();
                ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL controller = new ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL(id, groupBLThread, "worker"+i);
                controller.start();

                //System.out.println("ID :"+id);
            }

            return code;
        }

        public int negaID(int id, String matricola) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            int code = -1;

            EntitySmartFarm esm = EntitySmartFarm.getInstance();

            EntityColtivazione coltivazione = esm.getColtivazioneBySerraID(id);

            if(coltivazione == null) return code;

            String matResp = coltivazione.getEntitySerra().getResponsabile().getMatricola();

            if (!matricola.equals(matResp)) return code;

            ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL controller = this.searchWorkerForID(id);

            if (controller == null) return code;

            code = controller.negaID();

            return code;

        }

        public int ripristinaRilevamento(int id, String matricola) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            int code = -1;

            EntitySmartFarm esm = EntitySmartFarm.getInstance();

            EntityColtivazione coltivazione = esm.getColtivazioneBySerraID(id);

            if(coltivazione == null) return code;

            String matResp = coltivazione.getEntitySerra().getResponsabile().getMatricola();

            if (!matricola.equals(matResp)) return code;

            ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL controller = this.searchWorkerForID(id);

            if (controller == null) return code;

            code = controller.ripristinaRilevamento();

            return code;
        }

        public int confermaId(int id, String matricola) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            int code = -1;

            EntitySmartFarm esm = EntitySmartFarm.getInstance();

            EntityColtivazione coltivazione = esm.getColtivazioneBySerraID(id);

            if(coltivazione == null) return code;

            String matResp = coltivazione.getEntitySerra().getResponsabile().getMatricola();

            if (!matricola.equals(matResp)) return code;

            ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL controller = this.searchWorkerForID(id);

            if (controller == null) return code;

            code = controller.confermaID();

            return code;

            // quindi se il code è negativo le matricole non combaciano, se positivo combaciano
        }

        protected ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL searchWorkerForID(int idSerra) {

            ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL[] th = new ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL[groupBLThread.activeCount()];

            groupBLThread.enumerate(th);

            int i=0;
            while(i<th.length) {
                if(th[i].getID() == idSerra) return th[i];
                i++;
            }
            return null;

        }

        private CoordinatorIntrusione() {
            groupBLThread = new ThreadGroup("workerCoordinator");
        }

        public void notifyProximityBySerraID(int idSerra, float value) {

            ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL thread = this.searchWorkerForID(idSerra);
            thread.proximityValueArrived(value);

        }

        public void notifyImageBySerraID(int idSerra, ArrayList<Integer> img) {

            ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL thread = this.searchWorkerForID(idSerra);
            thread.imgArrived(img);
        }

        public static CoordinatorIntrusione getInstance() {
            if (coordinator == null) {
                synchronized(CoordinatorIntrusione.class){ //Serve la sincronizzazione visto che è solo lettura
                    if(coordinator == null){
                        coordinator = new CoordinatorIntrusione();
                    }
                }
            }
            return coordinator;
        }
    }
```

CONTROLLERRILEVAINTRUSIONEBL:

```
    public class ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL extends Thread{

        private int id;
        private float[] valoreProssimita;
        private ArrayList<Integer> img;
        private static final float criticalProxValue =5;

        private Semaphore proxsem;
        private Semaphore camsem;
        private Semaphore ripristinasem;
        private Semaphore waitsem ;


        protected int rilevaVolti() {
            //TODO with python script
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            return 0;
        }

        public synchronized int negaID() {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            int code = 0;
            if (waitsem.getQueueLength() > 0)   {
                waitsem.release();
                code = 1;
            }
            else    code = -1;
            return code;

        }

        public synchronized int ripristinaRilevamento() {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            int code = 0;

            //System.out.println(ripristinasem.getQueueLength());

            if (ripristinasem.getQueueLength() > 0) {
                ripristinasem.release();
                code = 1;
            }
            else    code = -1;

            //System.out.println(ripristinasem.getQueueLength());

            return code;

        }
        public synchronized int confermaID() {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            int code = 0;
            if (waitsem.getQueueLength() > 0)   {
                waitsem.release();
                code = 1;
            }
            else    code = -1;
            return code;
        }

        public int getID() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setID(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            EntitySmartFarm esm = EntitySmartFarm.getInstance();

            EntityColtivazione colt = esm.getColtivazioneBySerraID(id);

            EntitySerra serra = colt.getEntitySerra();

            EntitySensore proximity = serra.getSensoreProssimita();

            EntitySensore camera = serra.getSensoreFotografico();

            //ProxySerra proxyserra = ProxySerra.getInstance();

            while (true) {
                //MonitoraggioProssimità
                //invio messaggio alla serra

                try {
                    proxsem.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                proximity.setValore(valoreProssimita);

                if(valoreProssimita[0] < criticalProxValue){

                    // invio messaggio camera alla serra

                    try {
                        camsem.acquire();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    float[] immagine = new float[img.size()];
                    int index = 0;
                    for (Integer value: img) {
                        immagine[index++] = value;
                    }
                    camera.setValore(immagine);

                    int ret = this.rilevaVolti();

                    if (ret == 0 || ret == -1) {
                        //New ProxyNotificationSystem

                        if (ret == 0) {
                            //ProxyNotificationSystem.inviosegnalazione();

                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Rome"), Locale.ITALY);
                            Date today = calendar.getTime();
                            Date ora = calendar.getTime();

                            int[] array = img.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();

                            serra.addIntrusione(today, "Selvaggina", array, ora);

                        } else {

                            try {
                                waitsem.acquire();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //proxynotsys.nviosegnalazione();
                        }

                        System.out.println("Thread: "+this.id+" bloccato");

                        try {
                            ripristinasem.acquire();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        System.out.println("Thread: "+this.id+" Sbloccato");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL(int id, ThreadGroup group, String threadName){
            super(group,threadName);
            this.id = id;
            valoreProssimita = new float[1];
            img = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            proxsem = new Semaphore(0);
            camsem = new Semaphore(0);
            ripristinasem = new Semaphore(0);
            waitsem = new Semaphore(0);
        }


        public void proximityValueArrived(float value) {
            valoreProssimita[0]=value;
            proxsem.release();
        }

        public void imgArrived(ArrayList<Integer> img) {
            this.img=img;
            camsem.release();
        }

    }
```

ENTITYSERRA (first "addIntrusione" method catches exception and does not work, second "addIntrusione" method does not catch but does not work anyway):

```
    public class EntitySerra {
        public EntitySerra() {
        }

        private java.util.Set this_getSet (int key) {
            if (key == vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_ENTITYSERRA_ENTITYEMPLOYERS) {
                return ORM_entityEmployers;
            }
            else if (key == vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_ENTITYSERRA_ENTITYSENSORES) {
                return ORM_entitySensores;
            }
            else if (key == vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_ENTITYSERRA_ENTITYINTRUSIONES) {
                return ORM_entityIntrusiones;
            }
            else if (key == vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_ENTITYSERRA_ENTITYLETTURAS) {
                return ORM_entityLetturas;
            }

            return null;
        }

        org.orm.util.ORMAdapter _ormAdapter = new org.orm.util.AbstractORMAdapter() {
            public java.util.Set getSet(int key) {
                return this_getSet(key);
            }

        };

        private int id;

        private java.util.Set ORM_entityEmployers = new java.util.HashSet();

        private java.util.Set ORM_entitySensores = new java.util.HashSet();

        private java.util.Set ORM_entityIntrusiones = new java.util.HashSet();

        private java.util.Set ORM_entityLetturas = new java.util.HashSet();

        private void setId(int value) {
            this.id = value;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getORMID() {
            return getId();
        }

        public void setORM_EntityEmployers(java.util.Set value) {
            this.ORM_entityEmployers = value;
        }

        public java.util.Set getORM_EntityEmployers() {
            return ORM_entityEmployers;
        }

        public final vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityEmployerSetCollection entityEmployers = new vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityEmployerSetCollection(this, _ormAdapter, vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_ENTITYSERRA_ENTITYEMPLOYERS, vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_MUL_ONE_TO_MANY);

        public void setORM_EntitySensores(java.util.Set value) {
            this.ORM_entitySensores = value;
        }

        public java.util.Set getORM_EntitySensores() {
            return ORM_entitySensores;
        }

        public final vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySensoreSetCollection entitySensores = new vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySensoreSetCollection(this, _ormAdapter, vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_ENTITYSERRA_ENTITYSENSORES, vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_MUL_ONE_TO_MANY);

        public void setORM_EntityIntrusiones(java.util.Set value) {
            this.ORM_entityIntrusiones = value;
        }

        public java.util.Set getORM_EntityIntrusiones() {
            return ORM_entityIntrusiones;
        }

        public final vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityIntrusioneSetCollection entityIntrusiones = new vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityIntrusioneSetCollection(this, _ormAdapter, vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_ENTITYSERRA_ENTITYINTRUSIONES, vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_MUL_ONE_TO_MANY);

        public void setORM_EntityLetturas(java.util.Set value) {
            this.ORM_entityLetturas = value;
        }

        public java.util.Set getORM_EntityLetturas() {
            return ORM_entityLetturas;
        }

        public final vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityLetturaSetCollection entityLetturas = new vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityLetturaSetCollection(this, _ormAdapter, vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_ENTITYSERRA_ENTITYLETTURAS, vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ORMConstants.KEY_MUL_ONE_TO_MANY);

        public String getNotifyInformationResponsabile() {
            //TODO: Implement Method
            String recapito = null;
            Iterator<EntityEmployer> it = ORM_entityEmployers.iterator();
            boolean trovato = false;
            while(trovato == false && it.hasNext()){
                EntityEmployer empTemp = it.next();
                if(empTemp.getTipo().equals("responsabile")){
                    trovato = true;
                    recapito = empTemp.getRecapito(); 
                }
            }

            return recapito;
        }

        public void salvaLettura() {
            //TODO: Implement Method
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void salvaLettura2() {
            //TODO: Implement Method
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void addIntrusione(java.util.Date data, String tipo, int[] img, java.util.Date ora) {
            //TODO: Implement Method
            EntityIntrusione intrusione = new EntityIntrusione (data, ora, tipo, img);

            //DA TESTARE IMPORTANTISSIMO
            ORM_entityIntrusiones.add(intrusione);
            try {
                //EntitySerraDAO.save(this);

                EntityIntrusioneDAO.save(intrusione);

            } catch (PersistentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        /*public synchronized void addIntrusione(java.util.Date data, String tipo, int[] img, java.util.Date ora){
            //TODO: Implement Method
            EntityIntrusione intrusione = new EntityIntrusione (data,ora,tipo,img);
            //DA TESTARE IMPORTANTISSIMO
            this.ORM_entityIntrusiones.add(intrusione);
            this.entityIntrusiones.add(intrusione);
            try {
                Stream<EntityIntrusione> stream =  this.ORM_entityIntrusiones.stream();
                // salva l'ultimo elem
                EntityIntrusioneDAO.save(stream.reduce((a, b) -> b).orElse(null)); 
            } catch (PersistentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }

        }*/

        public EntitySerra(vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySerraDAO serra) {
            //TODO: Implement Method
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public String[] getNotifyInformationEmployers() {
            //TODO: Implement Method
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySensore getSensoreProssimita() {
            EntitySensore sensProssimita = null;
            Iterator<EntitySensore> it = ORM_entitySensores.iterator();
            boolean trovato = false;
            while(trovato == false && it.hasNext()){
                EntitySensore sensTemp = it.next();
                if(sensTemp.getTipo().equals("prossimita")){
                    trovato = true;
                    sensProssimita = sensTemp;
                }

            }
            return sensProssimita;
        }

        public vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySensore getSensoreFotografico() {
            EntitySensore sensFotocamera = null;
            Iterator<EntitySensore> it = ORM_entitySensores.iterator();
            boolean trovato = false;
            while(trovato == false && it.hasNext()){
                EntitySensore sensTemp = it.next();
                if(sensTemp.getTipo().equals("cam")){
                    trovato = true;
                    sensFotocamera = sensTemp;
                }

            }
            return sensFotocamera;
        }

        public vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityEmployer getResponsabile() {
            //TODO: Implement Method
            EntityEmployer responsabile = null;
            Iterator<EntityEmployer> it = ORM_entityEmployers.iterator();
            boolean trovato = false;
            while(trovato == false && it.hasNext()){
                EntityEmployer empTemp = it.next();
                if(empTemp.getTipo().equals("responsabile")){
                    trovato = true;
                    responsabile = empTemp; 
                }
            }

            return responsabile;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(getId());
        }

    }
```

ENTITYINTRUSIONEDAO:

```
    public class EntityIntrusioneDAO {

    public static boolean save(vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityIntrusione entityIntrusione) throws PersistentException {
        try {
            vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.ProgettoPSSSAgosVersionPersistentManager.instance().saveObject(entityIntrusione);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new PersistentException(e);
        }
    }


}
```

PERSISTENT MANAGER:

```
public class ProgettoPSSSAgosVersionPersistentManager extends PersistentManager {

        private static PersistentManager _instance = null;
        private static SessionType _sessionType = SessionType.THREAD_BASE;
        private static int _timeToAlive = 60000;
        private static JDBCConnectionSetting _connectionSetting = null;
        private static Properties _extraProperties = null;
        private static String _configurationFile = null;

    private ProgettoPSSSAgosVersionPersistentManager() throws PersistentException {
        super(_connectionSetting, _sessionType, _timeToAlive, new String[] {}, _extraProperties, _configurationFile);
        setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
    }

    public String getProjectName() {
        return PROJECT_NAME;
    }

    public static synchronized final PersistentManager instance() throws PersistentException {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new ProgettoPSSSAgosVersionPersistentManager();
        }

        return _instance;
    }

    public void disposePersistentManager() throws PersistentException {
        _instance = null;
        super.disposePersistentManager();
    }

    public static void setSessionType(SessionType sessionType) throws PersistentException {
        if (_instance != null) {
            throw new PersistentException("Cannot set session type after create PersistentManager instance");
        }
        else {
            _sessionType = sessionType;
        }

    }

    public static void setAppBaseSessionTimeToAlive(int timeInMs) throws PersistentException {
        if (_instance != null) {
            throw new PersistentException("Cannot set session time to alive after create PersistentManager instance");
        }
        else {
            _timeToAlive = timeInMs;
        }

    }

    public static void setJDBCConnectionSetting(JDBCConnectionSetting aConnectionSetting) throws PersistentException {
        if (_instance != null) {
            throw new PersistentException("Cannot set connection setting after create PersistentManager instance");
        }
        else {
            _connectionSetting = aConnectionSetting;
        }

    }

    public static void setHibernateProperties(Properties aProperties) throws PersistentException {
        if (_instance != null) {
            throw new PersistentException("Cannot set hibernate properties after create PersistentManager instance");
        }
        else {
            _extraProperties = aProperties;
        }

    }

    public static void setConfigurationFile(String aConfigurationFile) throws PersistentException {
        if (_instance != null) {
            throw new PersistentException("Cannot set configuration file after create PersistentManager instance");
        }
        else {
            _configurationFile = aConfigurationFile;
        }

    }

    public static void saveJDBCConnectionSetting() {
        PersistentManager.saveJDBCConnectionSetting(PROJECT_NAME, _connectionSetting);
    }
}
```

The exception caught is:

```
org.orm.PersistentException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityIntrusione._vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySerra.ORM_EntityIntrusionesBackref
    at org.orm.PersistentSession.saveOrUpdate(PersistentSession.java:598)
    at org.orm.PersistentManager.saveObject(PersistentManager.java:326)
    at vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityIntrusioneDAO.save(EntityIntrusioneDAO.java:304)
    at vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySerra.addIntrusione(EntitySerra.java:146)
    at vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.business_logic.ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL.run(ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL.java:139)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityIntrusione._vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySerra.ORM_EntityIntrusionesBackref
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:625)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:647)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:642)
    at org.orm.PersistentSession.saveOrUpdate(PersistentSession.java:596)
    ... 4 more
org.orm.PersistentException: org.orm.PersistentException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityIntrusione._vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySerra.ORM_EntityIntrusionesBackref
    at vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityIntrusioneDAO.save(EntityIntrusioneDAO.java:309)
    at vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySerra.addIntrusione(EntitySerra.java:146)
    at vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.business_logic.ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL.run(ControllerRilevaIntrusioneBL.java:139)
Caused by: org.orm.PersistentException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityIntrusione._vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySerra.ORM_EntityIntrusionesBackref
    at org.orm.PersistentSession.saveOrUpdate(PersistentSession.java:598)
    at org.orm.PersistentManager.saveObject(PersistentManager.java:326)
    at vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityIntrusioneDAO.save(EntityIntrusioneDAO.java:304)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntityIntrusione._vista_architetturale_gestoresmartfarm.entity2.EntitySerra.ORM_EntityIntrusionesBackref
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:625)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:647)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:642)
    at org.orm.PersistentSession.saveOrUpdate(PersistentSession.java:596)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Seems showed stack trace of exception is not full.

Comment: You should add the full stacktrace (we don't even know what kind of exception it is). Also you should change all your `try catch` blocks around the `acquire()` methods. You should not continue if your acquisation fails.

Comment: ok I updated the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the **Error Handling** method when generating ORM code. May I know which option you selected? 
[image]